# Alamofire header error with https but working with http

Tags: php, swift, alamofire

Developing IOS app with Alamofire for apis. Backend we use php. All the apis works perfectly with http:// request. But when we change the api to https:// Only apis without header (token) works. All others fails.

which seams the header is not received by server.

**Swift code**

```
func postRequestWithAlamoFire(somedata: [String: Any], method: String,url: URL, withSuccessionBlock successBlock: @escaping (_ response: Any) -> Void, andFailureBlock failureBlock: @escaping (_ error: Error) -> Void) {

    var header = HTTPHeaders()
    if method != API_LOGIN && method != API_SIGNUP && method != API_VERIFY_OTP && method != API_RESEND_OTP && method != API_FORGOT_PASSWORD && method != API_SOCIAL_SIGNUP && method != API_VERSION_CHECK
    {
        header = HTTPHeaders.init(["Authorization" : Constants.shared.GetValue(USER_ACCESS_TOKEN), "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"])
        debugPrint("Header: ", header)
    }

    AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: somedata, encoding: URLEncoding.queryString, headers: header).responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint("URL: \(url)-->\(somedata)\n\(method) Resp: ", "\n", response.result)
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let data = response.value as? NSDictionary {
                successBlock(GrouppalSeparateParam().separate(params: data, methodName: method))
            }
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            failureBlock(error)
        }
    }
}
```

The response i get is

```
    "Header: " Content-Type: multipart/form-data

Authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGc8u4Jub25lIiwianRpIjoie1wib3duZXJcIjpcInVzZXJcIixcInVpZFwiOjQxLFwiZXhwXCI6MTY0Mzk2ODgxOX0ifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9ncm91cHBhbC5pbiIsImlhdCI6MTYxMjQzMjgxOSwibmJmIjoxNjEyNDMyODE5LCJleHAiOjE2NDM5Njg4MTksInVpZCI6NDEsImp0aSI6IntcIm93bmVyXCI6XCJ1c2VyXCIsXCJ1aWRcIjo0MSxcImV4cFwiOjE2NDM5Njg4MTl9In0.
"URL: https://domianname.com/folder/api_endpoint.php?action=feed_list-->[\"page\": 0]\nfeed_list Resp: " "\n" Swift.Result<Any, Alamofire.AFError>.success({
    msg = "Invalid Access!";
    result = 0;
```

})

Php Code

```
    class API 
{   
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->jwtUtils = new JWTUtils();
    }

    public function authenticateAPI(){
        $headers = apache_request_headers();
        
        if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
            $bearerToken = trim($headers["Authorization"]);
            $bearerToken = str_replace("Bearer ", "", $bearerToken);
            $bearerToken = str_replace("BEARER ", "", $bearerToken);
            
            $validateToken = $this->jwtUtils->validateToken($bearerToken);
            // throw new Exception(json_encode($validateToken));
            if(!$validateToken['result'])
                throw new Exception($validateToken['msg']);
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && ($_REQUEST['action']=='util_test' || $_REQUEST['action']=='util_versionchk' || $_REQUEST['action']=='user_login' || $_REQUEST['action']=='user_msignup'|| $_REQUEST['action']=='user_esignup' || $_REQUEST['action']=='user_verifyotp' || $_REQUEST['action']=='user_resendotp' || $_REQUEST['action']=='user_forgotpass' || $_REQUEST['action']=='util_upload' || $_REQUEST['action']=='util_notification' || $_REQUEST['action']=='admin_login' || $_REQUEST['action']=='util_ifsc' || $_REQUEST['action']=='util_payouts' || $_REQUEST['action']=='util_invitelink'))
                return TRUE;
            else
                throw new Exception("Invalid Access!");
        }
    }
}
```

$validateToken returns

(Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x78e74b80 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.

Comment: I don't think we have enough info to be able to answer it.  Headers being added/stripped is normally in your httpd server config.  What httpd server are you using? Apache? Nginx?  I'd start looking there and see if there are differences between the httpd config file sections for http vs https.

Comment: From Android the https is working fine . Only in swift its not working

Comment: Resolved the issue. 
The problem is when i use http:// the header gives "Authorization" but when i use https:// it gives "authorization" i don't know why. So i changed my php coding to check for both.